# Taizé prayer in Bucharest: where?

Tags: romania, religion, bucharest

Where I live, use to go to the Taizé prayer in the nearby parish. I know this is international and that many people, after coming back to Taizé, start to pray the same way in small groups within the local church.

Now I'm going to Bucharest for 5 days and I would like to join a Taizé prayer in the local community (if any).

Do you know if there are any regular Taizé prayers in Bucharest and if it would be possible to get in contact with them in advance to ask for information about how to join the prayer?

I had a look at the taize.fr website but I found no useful information.

Comment: If you know a few months in advance where you will be traveling, you should contact Taizé itself, not just look at its website. But you will have to give them time to reply. I know for sure that they ask all groups that visit, and many individuals, whether there are regular prayer meetings where they live. They do that so they can share that information with others, so ask for it.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet actually comes from the main taize.fr site, where they mention St Sylvester's church in Bucharest, when talking about [Brother Alois' visit to Romania in 2008](http://www.taize.fr/en_article6983.html):

> Fr. Bordasiu, current parish priest of St. Silvester, who began
>   sending groups to Taizé from Bucharest in 1990, remembered the visits
>   of Brother Grégoire already in the 1970s.

So certainly, if anyone can help you with taize prayer or finding a community of those who associate with the order, St Sylvester seems like the place to start.

[Location of the church on Google Maps](https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Strada+Silvestru+36,+Bucure%C8%99ti,+Romania/@44.443152,26.11504,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x40b1ff3450d9bfff:0x732bd63c3f92d3c0)

[Pictures and more details on Tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Attraction_Review-g294458-d7003077-Reviews-St_Sylvester_Church-Bucharest.html)

Comment: actually the prayer isn't active anymore (I contacted the brothers). The issue is also that there is no way to communicate with people of the st. Sylvester church (no email, no phone etc).

Comment: @DanieleB I assumed you'd just go visit the church itself - that's why I gave the location and details of it...

Comment: @Mark_Mayo yes thank you! I appreciated it very much!